# How to get all the JSON records saved instead of the last record only

Tags: json

Here is my code, I'm trying to get all the records saved in the JSON file, but I end up with the last record only. Thanks!

```
try {
        $output = $web_service->query($input);
        if($output['HTTP_OK'] == true) {
            foreach (json_decode($output['DATA']) as $obj) {
                print_r($obj);
            }
        }
    }

    file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($obj));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
try {
    $output = $web_service->query($input);
    if($output['HTTP_OK'] == true) {
        print_r($output['DATA']);
        foreach (json_decode($output['DATA']) as $obj) {
            print_r($obj);
        }

    }

file_put_contents("data.json", $output['DATA']);
```